# Blank page on headless Selenium tests run with Jenkins

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, xvfb

Headless Selenium tests can be well run on my machine (yup, I should definitely move in this ideal place where problems doesn't exist).

However, when I launch those tests via Jenkins, none of the page elements are found. I took a screenshot to figure out why, and it shows a blank page.

This is how I instanciate my headless Chrome browser.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920x1080");
chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximised");
chromeOptions.addArguments("enable-automation");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

I have a guess but my coworker says it can't be this: should I install Xvfb on Jenkins server? I mean, is it mandatory? (I must be at least 51% sure before trying this approach ^^)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the tests run in headless mode on your machine as well?

Comment: Which version of Chrome and ChromeDriver are installed on the Jenkins machine?

Comment: @GregBurghardt yes they run headless on my machine wtih no problem. For the versions, I guess they are ok, because I'm using `webdrivermanager`...

Comment: That's not necessarily true. The versions matter a lot. A version mismatch between browser and web driver can cause this.

Comment: @GregBurghardt hi, `google-chrome --product-version` returns `81.0.4044.138`, and then I see `Starting ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.138`, so I guess there are no compatibility issues... I'm definitely stuck :(

Comment: @Y-B Cause: Was this ever resolved?

Comment: @ShashankKadne not yet. I'll keep you updated

Comment: @Y-B Cause: You usually will not need xvbf. It's only required if you want to run your tests in head mode. Also can you confirm if the site that you are trying to access has security issues? If so you will need to accept insecure certs by setting the option in chrome driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried lots of solutions but it turned out that Jenkins wasn't allowed to access the resources I needed to test. So... I couldn't solve it myself anyway. Sysadmins did.